# Is there a way to conditionally display a CMS block based on URL params?

Tags: blocks

I would like to display CMS blocks only if they match a specific param pattern.

So for example, if the param are something like:

`example.com?p=1`

I would like to display block A

if the param is something like:

`example.com?p=2`

I would like to display block B

Is it possible to do this using Magento's `{magentocode}}` syntax?

Comment: not possible as per as my thought

Answer (score 0):

Not within the CMS blocks. Those are called *static* blocks for a reason: They are meant to show the same content all the time and also will be cached.

You would have to implement the conditions outside the CMS block, how exactly depends on where the block is shown.